# Problems making arrays with user input in Python

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I've got a window using tkinter where the user can type in the value for an array: i.e. `"x","y","z"`. Then when I go to put that data into an array (`myarray = [myuserinput]`) it puts two single quotes around it like this: `'"x","y","z"'`. This prevents the array from being able to be read -  *IndexError: list index out of range*
Also, when I try to make another array using some data and a while loop it inserts alot of brackets infront of it:

```
    firstcounter = "1"
    thecounters = "0"
    while int(firstcounter) < newfilter :
        thecounters = thecounters,0
        firstcounter = int(firstcounter) + 1
    counters = [thecounters]
```

This code also results in an list index out of range error

Please Help!!!!

Comment: You have two questions here. Ask one question, get an answer. If you still have another question, open a new one.

Comment: kindly refer to them as **list**

Comment: @msvalkon I'll remember that next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a wild guess here and assume that you're dealing with a string in which the elements are delimited by a `,`.

You'll need to split the string to get a list of the elements.

```
myarray = myuserinput.split(",")
```

Example:

```
In [3]: myuserinput = '"x","y","z"'

In [4]: my_list = myuserinput.split(",")

In [5]: my_list
Out[5]: ['"x"', '"y"', '"z"']
```

You can replace the `""` *before* you split:

```
In [11]: myuserinput = myuserinput.replace('"', '')

In [12]: myuserinput
Out[12]: 'x,y,z'
```